# Multiple image upload using MultiPartRequest: Content size below specified contentLength

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to upload multiple images to the server. I am using http.MultipartRequest.

## Main Error Noticed

Unhandled Exception: Content size below specified contentLength.  76 bytes written but expected 130707.

## Error

```
E/flutter (12577): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Content size below specified contentLength.  76 bytes written but expected 130707.
E/flutter (12577): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:65:7)
E/flutter (12577): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12577): #1      BaseRequest.send (package:http/src/base_request.dart:116:35)
E/flutter (12577): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12577): #2      CreateCarDS.uploadImage (package:usedcars_flutter/data_service/create_car_ds.dart:141:34)
E/flutter (12577): #3      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:6)
E/flutter (12577): #4      CreateCarDS.uploadImage (package:usedcars_flutter/data_service/create_car_ds.dart:115:44)
E/flutter (12577): #5      AddPageState._editCarNetwork.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:usedcars_flutter/screens/tabs/add_page.dart:1042:36)
E/flutter (12577): #6      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1141:30)
E/flutter (12577): #7      AddPageState._editCarNetwork.<anonymous closure> (package:usedcars_flutter/screens/tabs/add_page.dart:997:13)
E/flutter (12577): #8      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter (12577): #9      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (12577): #10     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
E/flutter (12577): #11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
E/flutter (12577): #12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
E/flutter (12577): #13     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
E/flutter (12577): #14     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
E/flutter (12577): #15     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
E/flutter (12577): #16     CreateCarDS.editCar (package:usedcars_flutter/data_service/create_car_ds.dart)
E/flutter (12577): #17     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
E/flutter (12577): #18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter (12577): #19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (12577): #20     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
E/flutter (12577): #21     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
E/flutter (12577): #22     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
E/flutter (12577): #23     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
E/flutter (12577): #24     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
E/flutter (12577): #25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
E/flutter (12577): #26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter (12577): #27     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
E/flutter (12577): #28     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
E/flutter (12577): #29     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (12577): #30     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (12577):
```

## UPLOAD FUNCTION

In this function, I get images as `List<File>`. I looped through the images List, and added each multipartFile to request.files. I think here I missed some code.

```
Future<http.StreamedResponse> uploadImages({
    int id,
    List<File> images,
  }) async {

    String apiUrl = CAR_IMAGE_ADD_URL + id.toString() + '/';
    debugPrint(apiUrl);

    var uri = Uri.parse(apiUrl);
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    request.headers.addAll({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Profile.instance.accessToken, 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});

    images.forEach((image) async {
      var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(image.openRead()));
      final length = await image.length();
      var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('image', stream, length,
          filename: basename(image.path));
      request.files.add(multipartFile);
    });

    var response = await request.send();
    print(response.statusCode);
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
    uploadStatusCode = httpStatusCodeFinder(response.statusCode);
    print(response);
    return response;
  }
```

1. Is my syntax correct?
2. Can I upload multiple images using the above method?

If you have any suggestions or answers, then it will be very helpful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are introducing a subtle error. By making the `forEach` closure `async` it is automatically returning a future - and will not get executed inline.

Prefer `for` to `forEach` when iterating a list.

```
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(apiUrl));
  request.headers.addAll({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Profile.instance.accessToken,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  });

  for (var image in images) {
    var stream = http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(image.openRead()));
    final length = await image.length();
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile(
      'image', // consider using a unique name per image here
      stream,
      length,
      filename: basename(image.path),
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use dio.
It is a better and more powerful http client.

https://pub.dev/packages/dio

You can easily upload multipart files and additionally receive the progress of the upload.
Furthermore you can create a httpservice that contains a static Dio, which will be created one time and accessed by getters. So you only need to put your authorization one time at initialization or set interceptors to the client.

Comment: I am a beginner to flutter. Can you provide an example code using the above case

Comment: Look at the link I posted @Alwin, there are many examples for each scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I think dio is more powerful than the http

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had photo as Uint8List and before request i wanted to create a file.

My problem was **missing await on the write function.**

```
await file.writeAsBytes(photo);
```

So function didn't finish writing probably and request was triggered.